# UIButton and UILabel not updating from UIButton outside of View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a `view` with a `UITabelView` in it that has movable rows that adjust buttons on a different `view` inside my `ViewController`.
When a row is moved the icons in the `view` should update. See below (notice the `[self refreshicons]`) :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
     NSInteger sourceRow = sourceIndexPath.row;
     NSInteger destRow = destinationIndexPath.row;
     id object = [shortcutApps objectAtIndex:sourceRow];

     [shortcutApps removeObjectAtIndex:sourceRow];
     [shortcutApps insertObject:object atIndex:destRow];
     [tableView reloadData];
     [self refreshIcons];

     NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDefaults setObject:shortcutApps forKey:@"ShortcutArray"];
}
```

this is `[self refreshicons]`

```
-(void)refreshIcons{
 icon1 = [shortcutApps objectAtIndex:0];
 NSLog(@"%@",icon1);
 [extraIcon1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[[icon1 lowercaseString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 extraIconLabel1.text = icon1;
 NSLog(@"%@",extraIconLabel1);
}
```

The NSLogs print the correct Strings, but the UILabel's and UIButton Images aren't updating. When a create a button that runs the same code as `[self refreshicons]` in the same `view` the icons exist, the code works as desired. But when the rows are moved or a button is pressed outside the `view` the label and button don't update.
Thoughts?

Comment: can you post some screenshots to have better idea

Comment: Why are you calling `reloadData` from the `moveRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: @rmaddy because my tableview has rows that need to change colour according to their index number

Comment: You should reload just the visible cells. But why do you need to call `refreshIcons` after reloading the table view? Shouldn't `cellForRowAtIndexPath` show the correct icon?

Comment: @rmaddy the icons are not in the UITableView, They are just in a regular View full of icons that need updating depending on the order they are in within the tableview array.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that whatever is happening in the `tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is overriding your icons.

The references in `refreshIcons` I'd guess are to outlets that you've kept around for reference to quickly update values, but they might be getting through the `reloadData` cycle.

Comment: i have added a button in the same UIView as the UITableView and the Icons still aren't updating to the images/text that needs to be displayed. The buttons that need refreshing are in a UIScrollView. Strangely NSLog shows the button Label to be the updated label, but the Label itself isn't updating.